# DNS points to the right IP, but I can't connect using DNS

Tags: linux-networking

**UPDATE**: This is now strictly a local problem, connecting remotely works (a dumb mistake I made.)  I think it's now it's a loopback issue, which is a different issue, and likely answered in another post.

I can connect remotely to my system using its IP address, the DNS returns the proper IP, but I can't connect via a DNS record.

i.e.

```
matt@pontus:~$ ssh fake.myDnsExample.com
ssh: connect to host fake.myDnsExample.com port 22: Network is unreachable
matt@pontus:~$ nslookup fake.myDnsExample.com
Server:     134.117.aaa.bbb
Address:    134.117.aaa.bbb#53

Non-authoritative answer:
fake.myDnsExample.com   canonical name = myDnsExample.com.
Name:   myDnsExample.com
Address: 50.100.XXX.YYY

matt@pontus:~$ ssh 50.100.XXX.YYY

           *connects*
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, this system is not in the DMZ but ports 22 and 80 are forwarded to it, it used to work (not sure what changed), and this also doesn't work locally, but again I can ssh to localhost (or any alias of localhost in ''/etc/hosts'')

Might this be an issue with Ubuntu? I don't imagine my router would interfere with this.

I should note that this is the same remotely and locally, for any protocol (SSH, Telnet, http.. etc)

Here is the output of ''ssh -v'',

From localhost:

```
ssh -v fake.myDnsExample.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/matt/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to fake.myDnsExample.com [50.100.XXX.YYY] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.100.XXX.YYY port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host fake.myDnsExample.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Remotely though pointed out I accidentally had an entry in ''/etc/hosts'' to a bad IP, and it now connects without issue, and I'm just an idiot. :)

Comment: Can you include the output of `ssh -v foo.example.com`? That should include information about what address it is connecting to.

Comment: Please consider not redacting your domain name.  These things tend to be much easier to solve if you're open with us.

Comment: Agreed, you probably have a DNS problem, and [the real hostname may be necessary](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) to investigate this.

Comment: That's a fair point.  Thanks for your help!  So, locally it still doesn't work, but it does remotely.  Turns out the system I was testing it remotely from had an entry in ''/etc/hosts'' to an old IP, I completely forgot about this, and didn't check since the local failure seemed so similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `/etc/hosts` file for this record. nslookup will not use this file in resolving DNS.

Also, check your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` it should say something like `hosts: files dns`

Comment: It actually reads ''hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns'', I'm not familiar with this file though and will have to read up on it.  Could this explain why it fails locally?  Thanks!

Comment: This means you have [Avahi](http://www.avahi.org/) installed, which is essentially an Open Source reimplementation of Apple's Bonjour. Avahi is trying to resolve the hostname, but fails to, and `NOTFOUND=return` causes it to quit after that. Based on [Ubuntu bug 140663](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss-mdns/+bug/140663), you may have configured your system with the same domain name as the host you're connecting to. Avahi thinks it is authoritative for it, so it doesn't fall back to DNS. Try changing it to `NOTFOUND=continue` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure it's working, but I'm also not sure I'm restarting my networking properly.  ''service networking'' can't seem to restart it properly.  I'll keep at it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading you comment correctly, you can connect to localhost (127.0.0.1).  However, in any scenario - by connecting via domain name to any protocol, you experience failure.

Since you stated things have changed, this leads me to believe that a firewall rule has been introduced where 127.0.0.1 is allowed, but IPs (including 50.100.XXX.YYY) are blocked.

Though I can't explain why you can connect with 50.100.XXX.YYY directly, unless one method resolves to a private IP address that is allowed.  This may have to do with "hosts" or hostname settings on the machine.

Although the router is opened up, it sounds like a firewall rule is blocking at fake.myDnsExample.com.

Comment: I thought so to, and should have mentioned it above, but my system firewall, ufw, is disabled/inactive.  But, turns out that this is now strictly a local problem, unfortunately I had entries in my ''/etc/hosts'' on the remote systems I was testing pointing at a bad IP.

Comment: best way to troubleshoot is check whether able to ping using domain name or not, because as given scenario IP is able to make connection means no firewall is blocking, so possible is domain name is not a valid.